"ReferenceError: upload_up_archive is not defined" when publishing npm library
Error creating my own npm library:

C:\Users\UsuaRIO\Desktop\Proyecto-Gym\Api\node_modules\subirimg\dist-node\index.js:15 upload_up_archive = /#PURE/function () {                    ^ ReferenceError: upload_up_archive is not defined      at Object. (C:\Users\UsuaRIO\Desktop\Proyecto-Gym\Api\node_modules\subirimg\dist-node\index.js:15:19)      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)      at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)      at Object. (C:\Users\UsuaRIO\Desktop\Proyecto-Gym\Api\src\client\client.service.ts:24:1)      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)      at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10

package.json
{
   "name": "subirimg",
   "version": "1.0.6",
   "description": "Return cloudinary image",
   "keywords": [
     "cloudinary",
     "Javascript",
     "js"
   ],
   "license": "MIT",
   "author": "Matias Marcelos Dei Castelli <matiasdeicastelli5@gmail.com>",
   "main": "dist-node/index.js",
   "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": ""
   },
   "scripts": {
     "build": "babel src -d dist-node"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "axios": "^1.6.8",
     "cloudinary": "^2.2.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "@babel/cli": "^7.24.5",
     "@babel/core": "^7.24.5",
     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.5"
   }
}

import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";

const cloudinary_upload = (
  cloud_name_cloudinary,
  api_key_name_cloudinary,
  api_secret_name_cloudinary
) => {
  return cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: cloud_name_cloudinary,
    api_key: api_key_name_cloudinary,
    api_secret: api_secret_name_cloudinary,
  });
};

const upload_up_archive = async (
  function_cloudinary_value,
  archivo,
  opciones
) => {
  try {
    cloudinary_upload(
      function_cloudinary_value.cloud_name,
      function_cloudinary_value.api_key_name_cloudinary,
      function_cloudinary_value.api_secret_name_cloudinary
    );
    const resultado = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(archivo, opciones);
    return resultado;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Error al subir el archivo a Cloudinary");
  }
};

export default { upload_up_archive };

GitHub repo
npm
Where I want to use the upload function in another project is with nest:
import { upload_up_archive } from 'subirimg';
      let image: string;
      if (file) {
         image =
            'https://p16-va-default.akamaized.net/img/musically-maliva-obj/1665282759496710~c5_720x720.jpeg';
      } else {
         const url = await upload_up_archive(
            {
               cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
               api_key_name_cloudinary: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
               api_secret_name_cloudinary: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
            },
            file,
         );
         console.log(url);
      }

Here I leave my index.js that is inside an src folder
I already have the library installed

export default { upload_up_archive };  don't do this. Use named exports or a single default but don't try and combine them. I'd recommend export { upload_up_archive }
